# Tab Layout not scrollable on large device

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i have view pager and for Tab Layout i am adding custom view

```
 for (int i = 0; i < TabsHeader.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = TabsHeader.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(PagerAdapter.getTabView(i));

    }

   TabsHeader.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    TabsHeader.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

but it working properly  but on few bigger devices it not scrolling . as i made TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE  why it not scrollable on some devices ?

Comment: what is a "strip"? please clarify

Comment: its <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: cool, thanks. now add only the relevant XML and Java code that adds the tablayout to your activity. paste the code into the question. for someone to help you, they need to know the contextually important information: xml layout, sibling elements, tablayout attributes.